# lazy load directive components in angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The modals in our angular app are each "component directives", which we add to the main html as:

```
<div component-one ng-show="componentOne" modal></div>
```

Where `modal` is a directive (with accompanying service) for showing/hiding various modals. It all works fine, except that the associated html template, js controller code and images are all loaded for every modal at page load, which puts unnecessary load on the browser/network at a critical time.

Q1: how can I prevent the template from being fetched and rendered until it is required? I.e. make the directive 'booting' code not fetch the html file (and not place it in the DOM) until its instructed to (which I could do via my `modals` service) (I looked into ng-if over ng-show, and it appear it would not achieve that)

Q2: as an alternative to 1, how can I delay the template fetch and render by n seconds, to atleast take it out of the page load bottleneck?

For reference, we're using ui-router for most of our state and navigation management, but the modals are implemented outside ui-router due to the need for them to exist in addition (on top of) to the ui-router managed templates. We're using angular 1.4.7

Comment: Look at the `ng-include` directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: thanks. i remember having issues with ng-include and ui-router (which turned me off using ng-include), but maybe that was when ng-include was wrapping ui-view, which this would not be, so i'll give it a shot.

Comment: Also look at the `ng-if` directive. `ng-show/ng-hide` change visibility. `ng-if` creates and destroys the DOM. --  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf